# SSHFS Mount using fstab is very slow

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, fstab, sshfs

I am using fstab to create a sshfs mount. It is working but it takes 5-10 minutes until it's executed. Is it possible to do it right away ? What makes it so slow ?

It's not about the speed of sshfs itself because I can manually use the command in the terminal with SSHFS and it's mounted right away. Using `oauto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions,noappledouble,nolocalcaches,no_readahead` options doesn't speed it up.

The following is the very similar line I put into my /etc/fstab
I added the linebreaks for better readability:

```
root@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:/server/path/
/local/path
fuse.sshfs
defaults,allow_other,nonempty,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub,reconnect,_netdev
0
0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [faster way to mount a remote file system than sshfs?](http://superuser.com/questions/344255/faster-way-to-mount-a-remote-file-system-than-sshfs)

Comment: @Yaron Edited question, it's no duplicate